# Create table with integer as primary key doesn't work not android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create table with integer as a primary key and it doesn't work.
here is the error:

> 11-02 11:17:24.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4781): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax error:
>   CREATE TABLE tremp_db ( 0 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date
>   TEXT, time TEXT, repeat TEXT, gamish TEXT, src_city TEXT, src_area
>   TEXT, dest_city TEXT, dest_area TEXT, price TEXT, who TEXT, phone
>   TEXT, email TEXT, text TEXT, update_time TEXT);

Someone knows what is the problem exactly?

Thanx...

here is the code:

```
public class Data
{
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = new String("db_carpool.db");
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7; 
    public static String TABLE_NAME = new String("tremp_db");
    public static int ID;
    public static String DATE = new String("date");
    private static String TIME = new String("time");
    private static String REPEAT = new String("repeat");
    private static String GAMISH = new String("gamish");
    private static String SRC_CITY = new String("src_city");
    public static String SRC_AREA = new String("src_area");
    public static String DEST_CITY = new String("dest_city");
    private static String DEST_AREA = new String("dest_area");
    private static String PRICE = new String("price");
    private static String WHO = new String("who");
    public static String PHONE = new String("phone");
    public static String EMAIL = new String("email");
    private static String TEXT = new String("text");
    private static String UPDATE_TIME = new String("update_time");

    final Data thisActivity = this;

    private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper = null; 
    private static Data datab = null;

    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    { 
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        { 
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null , DATABASE_VERSION); 
        } 

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " 
                    + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                    + DATE + " TEXT, " 
                    + TIME + " TEXT, " 
                    + REPEAT + " TEXT, " 
                    + GAMISH + " TEXT, " 
                    + SRC_CITY + " TEXT, " 
                    + SRC_AREA + " TEXT, " 
                    + DEST_CITY + " TEXT, " 
                    + DEST_AREA + " TEXT, " 
                    + PRICE + " TEXT, " 
                    + WHO + " TEXT, " 
                    + PHONE + " TEXT, " 
                    + EMAIL + " TEXT, " 
                    + TEXT + " TEXT, " 
                    + UPDATE_TIME + " TEXT" + ");"); 
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME); 
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

and here is the code of the function that insert into table

```
void NewTremp(Tremp tremp, Context context)
    {       
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(ID, tremp.id);
        values.put(DATE, tremp.date);
        values.put(TIME, tremp.time);
        values.put(REPEAT, tremp.repeat);
        values.put(GAMISH, tremp.gamish);
        values.put(SRC_CITY, tremp.src_city);
        values.put(SRC_AREA, tremp.src_area);
        values.put(DEST_CITY, tremp.dest_city);
        values.put(DEST_AREA, tremp.dest_area);
        values.put(PRICE, tremp.price);
        values.put(WHO, tremp.who);
        values.put(PHONE, tremp.phone);
        values.put(EMAIL, tremp.email);
        values.put(TEXT, tremp.text);
        values.put(UPDATE_TIME, tremp.update);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 

        long rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
//      handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
```

Comment: what is 0 INTEGER in create table statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the type of `public static int ID;` to String:

```
public static String ID = "_id";
```

If you want to use the db with a CursorAdapter the ID column needs to be named "_id"

**EDIT:**

The `ID` of type `String` is just the name of the column. The type of the column is defined in  your create table statement:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " 
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

Because you used an `int` as column name, your column was named after the string representation of this integer.

Comment: ok, thanx.... but i want it to be autoincrement, will it work if it will be string instead of integer?

Comment: Yes it will work. It's just the name of the column, the type is defined in the CREATE_TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to **give INTEGER values as a Column name,** SO SQLite doesn't allowed that.

```
Try to give any valid string column name for Integer ID type column like, as Herrmann suggested "_id" as a string.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key field name is `0`. SQL fields should start with a letter. [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) is PostgreSQL rules for field names (should be similar for SQLite). If you really want to keep the field name as "0" you could try putting in in quotes ("").